# Detect browser "back" input for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension which performs a certain action when the user enters the a "back" navigation action.

ie: they click the back button in the browser, or they swipe backwards with 3 fingers on a macbook pro, or if they enter the shortcut alt + left arrow.

How can I detect these actions? Should I create some type of listener or handler which accounts for each one individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation).

Start monitoring the details for each transition type that you mentioned. And then try to do something with this information.

```
chrome.experimental.webNavigation.onCommitted(function(details){
    console.log(details);
});
```

Comment: While this would work when there's an actual page in the tab history stack, it wouldn't fire the event when there's nothing to go "back" to.